# What's a good approach to clean up (DRY) this controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, dry

I have an action being performed on every create, update and update_status methods on my controller, But I feel that I am repeating myself, and would really appreciate some help on a better approach to write this.

I've abstracted the update logic to a service, but the parameters are different, on every method of my controller.

```
def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)
    @story.creator = current_user

    if @story.save

      next_state = StoryStateService.new(@story, current_user, nil).call

      if next_state 
        @story.update_column(:status_id, next_state) 
      end 

      redirect_to stories_path
    else
      render 'stories/new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])   

    if @story.update(story_params)

      next_state = StoryStateService.new(@story, current_user, nil).call

      if next_state 
        @story.update_column(:status_id, next_state) 
      end  

      redirect_to stories_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def update_story_status_event
    story = Story.find(params['story_id'])
    sub_action = params['sub_action']

    next_state = StoryStateService.new(story, current_user, sub_action).call

    if next_state 
      story.update_column(:status_id, next_state) 
    end

    redirect_to stories_path
  end
```

As you can see, I have

```
   next_state = StoryStateService.new(story, current_user, sub_action).call

    if next_state 
      story.update_column(:status_id, next_state) 
    end
```

being repeated on three methods, but on regular create and update, I dont need to send a sub_action param (string).

Comment: Well, extract that piece in its own method. Would already be an improvement.

Comment: Thanks Sergio! should I create the new method on the controller?

Comment: from `next_state = ...` to `redirect_to stories_path` is the same code. Move that to a method like `def update_status` with the code `next_state = StoryStateService.new(@story, current_user, nil).call;if next_state;@story.update_column(:status_id, next_state); end;redirect_to stories_path;end`

Comment: This question should be at codereview https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just extract the advance of the story, anything more than that would be overkill to me, given the simplicity of everything else.

```rb
def create
  @story = Story.new(story_params)
  @story.creator = current_user

  if @story.save
    advance_story @story

    redirect_to stories_path
  else
    render 'stories/new'
  end
end

def update
  @story = Story.find(params[:id])

  if @story.update(story_params)
    advance_story @story

    redirect_to stories_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def update_story_status_event
  story = Story.find(params['story_id'])
  sub_action = params['sub_action']

  advance_story story, sub_action

  redirect_to stories_path
end

private 

def advance_story(story, sub_action = nil)
  next_state = StoryStateService.new(story, current_user, sub_action).call

  if next_state
    story.update_column(:status_id, next_state)
  end
end
```

Comment: BTW, you'll need to add an explicit transaction in update and create to make sure all changes to DB happen or nothing happens. `ApplicationRecord.transaction do ... end`

Comment: Thanks a lot Roger, added your suggestion. Valeu cara!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `StoryStateService` is doing, but if it is dealing with updating a number of models, then you can also make a module or class and put it in the `lib` directory.

The other option is (this may be more preferable for `Story.find()`) is to use `before_action` callback. (https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_action)

e.g.

As you are using `Story.find()` in `update` and `update_story_status_event` you can do the following:

`before_action :find_story, :only => [:update, :update_story_status_event]`

```
   def find_story
     @story = Story.find(params[:id])
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
     # handle error here
   end
```

Comment: Hi Mishal, good point. Thanks for the feedback, StoryStateService, updates a status_id column on the story model, if it passes some business rules.